# Creating a grid of numbers in python using a list

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to write a program that accepts a number , n. The program will print out the numbers n to n+41 as 6 rows of 7 numbers. The first row will contain the values n to n+6, the second , the values n+7 to n+7+6 and so on.

Sample I/O:

Enter the start number: -2

-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9 10 11

12 13 14 15 16 17 18

19 20 21 22 23 24 25

26 27 28 29 30 31 32

33 34 35 36 37 38 39

The sample I/O looks a little weird on here but I'm sure you can see it.

I understand how to use nested loops to make a triangle but I cannot understand how to print it in a square with the next line have the previous line's value + 1.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Sounds like homework. Perhaps you can share what code you've written so far and re-phrase your question to ask for help with a specific problem rather than a "code this for me" request.

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and ease to answer it.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I've gone through all the slides that were given to us and still cant work out how to do it. I was thinking you could break up the list of n to n+41 into groups and then print them in rows but I don't know how to do that and cannot find the resources to help

Answer (score 0):

Before giving you a possible solution, I suggest you carefully read the lots of information about the Python language that there is both on StackOverflow and, in general, on the internet.

You will probably find answers to your questions simply by reading.

This could be one of the methods, if I understand the question correctly, to get the output you want:

```
# WITHOUT LIST
n = int(input('Enter the start number: '))
printed_values = 0
row_lenght = 7 # values for row
print('\nOUTPUT:\n')
for i in range(n, n+42, 1):
    print(i, end='\t')
    printed_values += 1
    if not printed_values%row_lenght:
        #a row is printed, reset printed_values
        printed_values = 0
        print('\n')

# WITH LIST
n = int(input('Enter the start number: '))
row_lenght = 7 # values for row
values = list(range(n, n+42, 1))
print('\nOUTPUT:\n')
for i in range(0, len(values), row_lenght):
    for value in values[i:i+row_lenght]:
        print(value, end='\t')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop is the key to your problem. It starts at the number entered and goes to that number plus 40 in steps of 6.

starter = int (input ('Enter a number : '))

```
for x in range (starter, starter + 40, 6) :
    for y in range (6) :
        print (x + y, end = ' ')
    print ()
```